# SQL query on a pair of fields together

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
name | action      |    action_timestamp
------------------------------------------
ABC  | START_PLAY  |  2017-02-02 10:00:00
PQR  | START_PLAY  |  2017-02-02 11:00:00
ABC  | END_PLAY    |  2017-02-02 10:30:00
PQR  | END_PLAY    |  2017-02-02 11:05:00
```

I want to get all the names who have started playing on or after a given timestamp and ended play on or before a given timestamp.

For example, if (action='START_PLAY' and action_timestamp >= 2017-02-02 10:00:00 ) and (action='END_PLAY' and action_timestamp <=2017-02-02 10:30:00) then the query should return me ABC

I am not sure how should I make the conditions (viz. start_play and action_timestamp) as one.

Comment: Do a self join using name. Check timestamp between start and end.

Comment: select * from Table1 where action_timestamp >= '2017-02-02 10:00:00' AND action_timestamp <= '2017-02-02 10:30:00'

Comment: I'm not fully comfortable with this table design. Can the same name show up several times, i.e. several starts and several ends? I'd consider one start column and one end column, i.e. keep them together in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'STARTING'
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t2.name = t1.name
    AND t2.action = 'START_PLAY'
    AND t2.timestamp >= '2017-02-02 10:30:00')
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 'ENDING'
    FROM yourtable t3
    WHERE t3.name = t1.name
    AND t3.action = 'START_PLAY'
    AND t3.timestamp <= '2017-02-02 10:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for each `name` exactly exists one row for `START_PLAY` and one row for `END_PLAY`, you can use something like the following:

```
select name, start_play, end_play
from (
        select name,
               max ( case when action = 'START_PLAY' then action_timestamp end) as start_play,
               max ( case when action = 'END_PLAY' then action_timestamp end) as end_play
        from yourTable 
        group by name
     )                 
where start_play > ...
  and end_play < ...
```

The nested query performs a single scan of the table and creates one row for each `name`, with `start_play` and `end_play` on the row; the outer part simply applies the filter on the rows resulting from the inner query.

Comment: Thanks. However, if we refer to the table, this wouldn't pull 'ABC' more than once if he did start and end within the given timestamps (multiple times)

Comment: Correct, due to the group, but if there are multiple occurrences I can't say if this result is right for you. Can you please post an exampe with multiple occurrences, explaining what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
select data.name from 
  (SELECT NAME,ACTION,ACTION_TIMESTAMP, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ACTION) AS count FROM ST3 
  where (action='START_PLAY' AND ACTION_TIMESTAMP>='02-FEB-17 10.00.00')OR 
  (ACTION='END_PLAY' AND ACTION_TIMESTAMP<='02-FEB-17 10.30.00')) data
where data.count=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intersect like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM TBL WHERE action='START_PLAY' and action_timestamp >= '2017-02-02 10:00:00'
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM TBL WHERE action='END_PLAY' and action_timestamp <= '2017-02-02 10:30:00'
```